# Run same tests for multiple ICollectionFixture in xUnit

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

I am curious if there is a solution for running the same tests for multiple `ICollectionFixture`s.
Like having `InlineData`, but over the whole test class, not only a method.

I need this functionality because I want to see if the tests are passing for different configurations (a switch, or connection string), that are being set in the `ICollectionFixture`.

For Example, I have the following fixtures:

```
public abstract class BaseTestConfigurationFixture : ConfigurationFixture<BaseTestConfigurationFixture>
{
    public BaseTestConfigurationFixture(bool shouldConfigure)
    {
        /// Configure 
    }
}

public class TestConfigurationFixtureVersionA : ConfigurationFixture<TestConfigurationFixtureVersionA>
{
    public TestConfigurationFixtureVersionA()
        : base(false)
    { }
}

public class TestConfigurationFixtureVersionB : ConfigurationFixture<TestConfigurationFixtureVersionB>
{
    public TestConfigurationFixtureVersionB()
        : base(true)
    { }
}
```

Now, I use those fixtures in the following collections:

```
public abstract class BaseTestEnvironmentCollection : ICollectionFixture<BaseTestConfigurationFixture>
{
    // This class has no code, and is never created. Its purpose is simply
    // to be the place to apply [CollectionDefinition] and all the
    // ICollectionFixture<> interfaces.     
}

[CollectionDefinition(nameof(TestEnvironmentCollectionVersionA))]
public class TestEnvironmentCollectionVersionA: ICollectionFixture<TestConfigurationFixtureVersionA>
{
    // This class has no code, and is never created. Its purpose is simply
    // to be the place to apply [CollectionDefinition] and all the
    // ICollectionFixture<> interfaces.     
}

[CollectionDefinition(nameof(TestEnvironmentCollectionVersionB))]
public class TestEnvironmentCollectionVersionB: ICollectionFixture<TestConfigurationFixtureVersionB>
{
    // This class has no code, and is never created. Its purpose is simply
    // to be the place to apply [CollectionDefinition] and all the
    // ICollectionFixture<> interfaces.     
}
```

I want my tests to run once with the configurations from `TestEnvironmentCollectionVersionA`, and then with the configurations from `TestEnvironmentCollectionVersionB`.

I also need to access `BaseTestConfigurationFixture` inside my test class. <s>This seems to cause problems, because if I annotate the test class only with one of my collection fixtures, `[Collection(nameof(TestEnvironmentCollectionVersionA))]`, I get the following error:</s>

> Message: 
>       The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: BaseTestConfigurationFixture testConfigurationFixture

This error does not appear if I use only one `TestFixture` and `CollectionFixture`, without inheritance.

I see that there is a restriction over `[CollectionAttribute]`, to not accept multiple such attributes.

What method should I consider, in order to achieve this functionality?

Thank you!

EDITED: 
Found the fix for the error bellow

> The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: BaseTestConfigurationFixture testConfigurationFixture

Comment: Each test should be atomic. Each test should have its own setups. Dont reuse configurations or values from test to test. Set up the configuration for each test.

Comment: Is [this](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/#using-the-theory-attribute-to-create-parameterised-tests-with-inlinedata-) what you're looking for?

Comment: @Josh I agree, the tests should be atomic, and they are, for each method. But as we have the `[Theory]` with `[InlineData]`, `[MemberData]` and `[ClassData]` attributes, I need something for global configuration. 
In my case, the variables for which the methods that I am unit testing should pass, are not the arguments, but the Environment Variables and AppSettings.

Comment: @Sjolfr Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I am looking for a way to pass different environment variables to my tests, not parameters. 
The `[InlineData]`, `[MemberData]` and `[ClassData]` were designed for different parameters.